# Как повернуть группу точек в 2D относительно произвольной точки?

Tags: математика, графика

Попробовал сделать по формулам : 
[image: x = x * cos(d) - y * sin(d), y = x * sin(d) + y *cos(d)]

И так как поворачивать нужно относительно произвольной точки, то от x и y предварительно отнимается расстояние этой точки от начала координат, а затем добавляется. Вот код(С++) :

```
    void rotate(int &x, int &y, const double &cosVal, const double &sinVal, const int &cx = 0, const int &cy = 0)
{
    const double _x = x - cx;
    const double _y = y - cy;
    x = round( _x * cosVal - _y * sinVal);
    y = round( _x * sinVal + _y * cosVal);
    x += cx;
    y += cy;
}
```

Но получается вот это (точка относительно которой крутится - центр треугольника) : [image: Треугольник деформируется и сходит с ума]

(гифка записана с момента когда треугольник уже начал деформироваться и "уезжать" от своего центра).

Comment: код скорее всего верный. Уверены что не погрешность округления накапливается? Попробуйте сохранить угол и каждый раз пересчитывать от начальной позиции заного.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы работаете с математикой с плавающей точкой, при этом используя переменные типа `int`! Естественно,  [накапливающиеся] ошибки округления дают совершенно нелепые результаты!

Используйте для координат переменные типа `double`, а в `int` их переводите **только для вывода графики** (и то можно неявно...)

```
void rotate(int &x, int &y, const double &cosVal, const double &sinVal,
            const int &cx = 0, const int &cy = 0)
```

должна превратиться в

```
void rotate(double &x, double &y, double cosVal, double sinVal,
            double cx = 0.0, double cy = 0.0)
```

Comment: Спасибо, стал считать в double и всё заработало.